# Как можно адаптировать right sidebar?

Tags: html5, адаптивная-верстка

Изучаю сейчас верстку и адаптацию. И вот практически все зафиксировалось, а как можно сделать, что-б при больших, расширенных размерах экрана, right sidebar не убегал, а был рядом с картинкой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.top{
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
}
.content{
  float:left;
  width:35%;
  height:auto;
   
}
.left_sidebar{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  height:auto;
}
.right_sidebar{
  float:right;
  width:25%;
}
.podval{
  clear:left;
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
}
.midle{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.content img
{
  padding-left:50px;
}
html, body,h1{margin: 0;}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 2000px){     
.top{
  
}
.left_sidebar{
  
}
.right_sidebar{
  
}
.podval{
  
}
.midle{

  
}
.content img{
  
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <header>
<div class="top">
    <h1> Немецкая овчарка <h1>
</div>
    
  </header> 
  
  <div class="midle">
  <div class="left_sidebar"> Немецкая овчарка — порода собак, изначально использовалась в качестве пастушьей и служебно-розыскной собаки.

Немецкая овчарка была получена в результате селекции и скрещивания некоторых разновидностей гуртовых собак Центральной и Южной Германии. Различают гладкошёрстную и длинношёрстную разновидности.

В наше время немецкие овчарки занимаются выставочной карьерой, охраной, а также являются собаками для семьи.</div>

  <div class="content"> <img src="nemetskaya-ovcharka8.jpg" width="400" height="300"> </div>
  
  <div class="right_sidebar"> Немецкая овчарка универсальна. Она одинаково хорошо может служить собакой-компаньоном, 
  охранной, защитной, сыскной, служебной и караульной собакой. Успешно используется в животноводстве как пастушья собака. 
  Чаще других пород используется на службе в армии, в полиции, для охраны государственных границ. Хорошо выдрессированная 
  немецкая овчарка незаменима при задержании преступника. Используется для сопровождения слепых. Прекрасно ладит с детьми.
  </div>
  </div>

  
  <footer>
  
 <div class="podval">
    <div>
  <div>
    <h3> Информация была взята из википедии. </h3>
  </div>
    </div>
 </div>   
  
  </footer>
 
  
  
  </body>
  
  
  </html>
```

Comment: Добавьте свой код к вопросу. Лучше на http://jsfiddle.net/ . А так в зависимости от потребностей, попробуйте css @ media свойство вроде @ media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {  ...  } Читать тут: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Добавил свой код